# Best or ideal way to update a repo on GitHub when the local on your computer is gone/deleted?

Tags: git, github

I wish to update a repo on GitHub but I ended up deleting it on my local Mac.
There seems to be so many different commands and possible combinations to do things that I worry I will permanently break something.
My only experience with Git is just committing the final project once it is complete.

I want to preserve the old history (to show that I made this one or two years ago, for example).

Should I just:

- Download a copy from GitHub?
- Clone it?
- Branch/Checkout?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Git commands can't remove files off of disk.  You must've removed it some other way.

Comment: Clone the repo again? Make changes, add, commit, push...

Comment: The scary part is `I ended up deleting it on my local Mac`.You hadn't pushed any of the work? Then that is lost unless you can find a way to get that local repo back to life through a Mac OS trick or a backup.

Comment: It is already on GitHub. I submitted it a year or two ago. I just want to update it. I am thinking about just cloning it and hope that the changes work.

Comment: You can also edit it directly on GitHub if you don't need to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to clone the repo again.